# Call Select Distinct by column name without any param in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to call Select Distinct By  from .

So in my Repository class for this table

```
List<String> findAllDistinctByName();
```

But this doesn't work as the findAllDistinctBy needs atleast one argument.

The problem is I want to get all the Distinct Names in the Name column.
One solution is to write my own Query String, but is there any other way to acheive it?

As mentioned in the problem statement I did try to have my query string and it works but is there any other way to achieve it without explicitly writing query string?

Comment: No, as the method would return the distinct results filtered by the `name` column/field of your entity. It won't return the distinct names. So you will need to write the query yourself.

Comment: You can use projection in your entity class. [Check this site](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections). Then `List<YourEntity.Name> findDistinctBy();` should work

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), the query should look so:

```
List<YourEntity> findAllDistinctByName(String name);
```

**UPDATE**

```
  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT en.name FROM Entity en")
  List<String> findAllDistinctNames();
```

Comment: no I don't want all the row with this disticnt name but all the distinct names in the column name.
So this will not work

Comment: one sec i`m going to update the answer

Comment: i updated the answer and also i want to add, for this case and not to do some extra work i recommend you to write something like i wrote in response, i mean  custom `@Query` .

Answer (score 0):

The option provided by @dauthDaert06 is a good solution or maybe a good hack where we project the entity on a view which just has the method for the column which we need and then create the method in repository class which looks like

```
List<EntityView> findAllDistictBy()
```

Not the prettiest of the solution but saves you from writing your custom query string and does the job more imperative way.